# Use Google Maps API on desktop Application

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Hi I'm writing an application in Java and I need to know if it is possible to use the Google Maps API. Because [this](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/developers_guide_java.html) are deprecated, I can only use the [javascript APIs](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/)

I want to use the already implemented function because I don't know how to replicate them

In particular that is what I need:
- I have the coordinates of an address A
- I have the size of the map (HxW)
- I have a the zoom Z to use
- I have a list of M markers to display in the map

I need to have the list of the markers currently visible in the mapview

If I can use the APIs I should use a way like this: I create the map object, I set the center, the size, the zoom. I put all the markers in the map (I think I can load a KML) and then I extract the only markers that are visible in the current map view.
This is the main procedure I need to implement, but I have others thing to calculate (like the bounds of the mapview and other stuffs)
I'd like to use the Google Maps APIs because those function I need are already implemented, but I don't know if I can do this...

Or maybe I can use a JavaScript Engine to run JS code in Java. But I never used tools like this and (if this solution is correct) I need a guide to use this. I've found Mozilla Rhino in wikipedia but I don't know is what I need

Comment: Check this link: [http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/10/30/building-maps-into-swing-app-with-jxmapviewer.html](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/10/30/building-maps-into-swing-app-with-jxmapviewer.html)

Comment: @ee: Why didn't you post this as an answer? Looks very promising.

Answer (score 0):

Repeating the answer provided by @ee:

See http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/10/30/building-maps-into-swing-app-with-jxmapviewer.html

Answer (score 0):

I used to add IE-browser controls into VB desktop applications ... that do support JS evaluation as well.

But maybe it's easier to develop in a real browser first -
because all code that interacts with the map needs to be in URL style: "javascript:somefunction(x.y);"